# Subsetting from a data frame with imposing a new structure

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Assume

```
data = structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(3, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

The two defined columns here are `a` and `b`, we can easily subset it using `subset`. However, if I'm looking at

```
subset(data, select = c("a","c"))
```

as one can expect, an error is returned:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, r, vars, drop = drop) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Is there a quick/convenient way to subset fields in such a way, that the missing columns would be appended as missing?

I.e., something along the lines of

```
data_sub <- subset.fill(data, select = c("a", "c"))
```

which would return a filled with `NA`'s missing columns that was not in the selection, i.e.:

```
data_sub = structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3), c = c(NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your aim is to maintain the subset function, and its properties, then you could do:

```
subset.fill=function(x,...){
  stopifnot(inherits(x,"data.frame"))
  cl <- match.call()
  nm <- eval(cl[grep("sel",names(cl))][[1]])
  x[setdiff(nm,names(x))] <-NA
  subset(x,...)
}

subset.fill(data,select=c("a","c"))
  a  c
1 1 NA
2 2 NA
3 3 NA

subset.fill(data,a>2)
  a b
3 3 1
```

Comment: Question regarding ``match.call()``: how do we import objects within ``subset.fill`` function? I.e., ``subset.fill(data, select = temp_frame$variables)``, where ``temp_frame`` is not a global object. In this case, ``eval(cl..`` part crashes since it cannot find the object ``temp_frame`` to eval from.

Comment: This does work as intended when the function is defined right next to its call, but not when it's defined globally. Though, I understand it is somewhat offtopic, it might still suit here?

Comment: @Nutle what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This `data.table` approach might work

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("a","c")
```

first, subset values of `cols` that are existing column-names in `data`, then add 'missing' columns with NA's

```
setDT(data)[, .SD, .SDcols = c( intersect( cols, names(data) ) ) ][, setdiff( cols, names(data) ) := NA][]
```

> ```
>    a  c
> 1: 1 NA
> 2: 2 NA
> 3: 3 NA
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a super straightforward way to do this. Subsetting columns by `NA` is unfortunately not as easy as subsetting rows by `NA`:

You could pre-fill non-existing columns as `NA`, then subset:

```
vars <- c("a","c")
replace(data, setdiff(vars, names(data)), NA)[vars]
#  a  c
#1 1 NA
#2 2 NA
#3 3 NA
```

Pretty easy to wrap this logic in a function then:

```
subset.fill <- function(data, x) {
    data[setdiff(x, names(data))] <- NA
    data[x]
}

subset.fill(data, c("a","c"))
#  a  c
#1 1 NA
#2 2 NA
#3 3 NA
```